# axios get request throws error on third party api

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, axios

Here is what I am trying and getting the bellow error using react app. I added the header but didn't work yet.

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://api.covid19api.com/summary', {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept': 'application/json'}}).then( (response) => {console.log(response)})
}
```

Error:

```
axios react createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

Comment: add a `.catch(()=>/*..*/)` statement to catch network errors and you are good to go

Comment: Note there is no Content-Type in a GET request since there is no content body. Doubt that is causing a problem setting the header but it is redundant

Comment: Also opening that url in browser address bar will see `"Error 1040: Too many connections"`. Would see same thing in your browser dev tools network when inspect the actual request